# PSEXEC returning garbage result. Why?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, psexec

I want to run a script on a remote windows 2008 server using PSEXEC of PSTOOLs..

I have installed PSTOOLs on my local machine and can run the PSEXEC command successfully as well. I connect to the remote server through it and it even picks up the script placed there. However, all I get is some sort of garbage values. And after that it states that the intended network is no longer available, which it is because I can see it and access it through the GUI.

I must mention that when I execute that script manually in the remote server it works fine. I am using windows remote desktop utility to connect to the server.

[image: Result of my PSEXEC statement]

Am I using PSEXEC the correct way? Or is the intended function of PSEXEC the same as what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

First you should have a look at the [help page](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html)
You must use `-w` to specify the remote working dir, and you can't call a .bat directly, you have to call cmd.exe. So try this
`psexec \\remoteserver -w "c:\users\admin\desktop\" cmd.exe /c youbatch.bat`

Comment: I actually have (.lnk) shortcut to a cmd instance which has a different home directory than a normal cmd instance...can a .lnk shortcut be used in place of where you mention the cmd.exe in your statement?
Like as follows:

`psexec \\remoteserver -w "c:\users\admin\desktop\" mycmd.lnk /c youbatch.bat`

Comment: I don't think so, what is in your link property?

Comment: In the properties, the 'Target' and 'Start in' paths are different for the .lnk cmd instance, so the intended script only runs through that...a normal cmd instance won't do.

Comment: you can specify the full target path to the command and the "start in" with the -w parameter : `psexec \\remoteserver -w "c:\starting folder\" c:\path\to\cmd.exe /c "c:\users\admin\desktop\yourbatch.bat"`

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a shot and get back. Although I tried a pretty close approximation to this one and it didn't work, but I am hopeful for this one.